# Google Firestore promises

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, eslint

I am currently trying to work out how to do basic queries with Firestore an NodeJS. I am getting the error "Expected catch() or return". I was hoping someone could explain why this is happening?

I am using express router to handle routes.

Method 1. ESLint error

```
userRouter.get("randomroutename", (req, res) => {

    const uid = req.params.uid;
    console.log("User: " + uid);

    let collectionRef = db.collection('col');
    collectionRef.add({foo: 'bar'}).then(documentReference => {
        console.log(`Added document with name: ${documentReference.id}`);
        res.status(200).send('SUCCESS');
    });
});
```

After looking around and trying out a few things this appears to work, however I am really confused as to why the return is needed. It doesn't really make sense to me why I need to return a promise when surely the function 'add' is returning the promise which I can access .then from.

Method 2. No error

```
userRouter.get("randomroutename", (req, res) => {

    const uid = req.params.uid;
    console.log("User: " + uid);

    let collectionRef = db.collection('col');
    return collectionRef.add({foo: 'bar'}).then(documentReference => {
        console.log(`Added document with name: ${documentReference.id}`);
        return res.status(200).send('SUCCESS');
    });
});
```

As per the docs (https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/CollectionReference.html), I believe method 1 should work.

Thanks for any help! (Very sorry if this is blindingly obvious I just can't get my head around it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message is saying "Expected catch() or return".  Note that you have two options here.  It would be appropriate to use `return` if you want to pass responsibility of the promise to the caller, but that's not what you want to do.  What you should do instead is catch any potential errors captured by the promise returned by `then`, and deal with them appropriately:

```
collectionRef.add({foo: 'bar'}).then(documentReference => {
    console.log(`Added document with name: ${documentReference.id}`);
    res.status(200).send('SUCCESS');
}).catch(err => {
    res.status(500);
})
```

With that, if there was an error getting adding the document for any reason, it will generate a 500 response to the client.

None of this is unique to Firestore.  This is just best practices in dealing with promises that ESLint is trying to get you to do.

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for your response however I don't believe this answers my question. I am completely aware that a catch statement is needed to send back an error. My question is why is the return statement needed? Without the return ESLint throws me the error "Expected catch() or returneslint(promise/catch-or-return)
". Many thanks, Leon

Comment: It shouldn't be needed if you use catch instead.  If you don't use catch, return is needed to pass responsibility of the promise to the caller, who should catch any errors.  You have a choice, but only one of them is correct here, since express isn't going to deal with that promise for you.

Comment: The formal documentation for eslint promise/catch-or-return is here: https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/catch-or-return.md

Comment: I have tried the catch statement, this is what is really confusing me. Upon adding the catch statement, ESLint throws the error "Each then() should return a value or throweslint(promise/always-return)". This just makes no sense to me because as you said " express isn't going to deal with that promise".

Comment: That's an entirely different problem.  You can resolve that by simply adding `return null` to the end if your `then` callback function.  The formal documentation for promise/always-return is here: https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/always-return.md

Comment: If you haven't guessed by now, you can get documentation for any one of these eslint warnings by doing a search.

Comment: In context, https://imgur.com/a/UQQFDqh . The idea of returning makes no sense in this context. Thanks for sending those docs across however that doesn't clarify anything for me.

Comment: If you don't want that warning then disable it in your eslint configuration.

Comment: I know I can disable the warning, I just don't understand why it is there. Why is it necessary to do "return collectionRef.add" instead of  "collectionRef.add".

Comment: The eslint documenation describes what it's trying to check, and provides you with a link for more information.  While it might not be strictly necessary for your code to function, lint warnings are trying to tell you where potential bugs are, and what you can do to clarify to the reader of your code that you know what you're doing.  You can disagree with the advice, but that won't stop the linter from complaining.  It's up to you - add the line of code to tell eslint you know what you're doing, or disable the warning.